# How to test the value this variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
myvariable="thisone"
versel = $("#" + myvariable);
alert (versel)
```

The above results in `[Objectobject]` displayed. I expect it to be **#thisone**. How to achieve that?

Either javascript or jQuery could do.

Please help.

Comment: **alert() is not a debugging tool**, it will always show `[Object, Object]` for any object, and a jQuery selector always returns an object, use the console.

Comment: `$()` is used for objects, so you get an object instead. Remove it to alert the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
console.log(versel);
```

This will show the object and its properties in your browser's developer console.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you expect it to be string, since you are using $. If you want just the string then remove that:

```
myvariable="thisone"
versel = "#" + myvariable;

alert (versel)
```

"$" will get the JQuery function, that is used for grabbing an element for example. An element such as a "input" can have a string value, for which you can use the "val()" function. So something like this:

alert($(versel).val()); //this will be the string value of the element retrieved by JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could just alert what you're passing to jQuery:

```
alert("#" + myvariable);
```